# Keep count of letter occurrences from text file?

Tags: java

I have to write a program where I have to find how many of each letter of the alphabet are in the file "test.txt" and divide that number by the total number of letters to find the percent occurrence of each letter (which I haven't done yet). However, I don't even know how to find the number of each letter present in the text file. Here is my extremely failed attempt. Can anyone please help me.

```
import java.io.*;
class EnglishAnalysis
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
  char letters[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
  FileReader fr = new FileReader("test.txt");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

  int count = 0;
  int totalLetters = 0;
  String lineCharacters [];
  String line;
  line = br.readLine();
  while (line != null)
  {
    lineCharacters = line.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < lineCharacters.length; i++)
    {
      if (!Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i)))
      totalLetters++;
      for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
      {
        if (line.charAt(i) == letters[j])
          count++;
          System.out.println(line.charAt(i) + " : " + count);
      }
    }
    line = br.readLine();
  }
  System.out.println(totalLetters);
  br.close();
  }
catch (IOException e) {}
}
}
```

Comment: Hint: Every char is an int. With a little math, you can convert `a` to `0`, `b` to `1` and so forth. Then it's just a matter of incrementing an int at that position in an array (This is assuming that all letters are lower case, as in your array)

Comment: Hint 2: Alternatively, you could use a `Map` (but an array is the more efficient solution).

Comment: your `count++;` is used globally for all the characters, you can set the count on a map as Elliott suggested.

Comment: One possible solution [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47704/counting-characters-in-a-text-file).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a different approach. Refer to code and code comments below for explanation.

Code:

```
package main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            char letters[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r',
                    's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
            double percentage[] = new double[26]; // declare a variable that will hold the percentages of each letter
            String path = "sample.txt";
            // Read all the contents of the file
            String text = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            // make a temporary copy of the content without all the letters
            String allLetters = text.replaceAll("[a-z]+", ""); //
            // Get the total number of characters in the file
            // by subtracting the new length (the length after all the letter has been
            // deleted) from the original length
            int totalNumOfLetters = text.length() - allLetters.length();

            // convert the contents into lower-case
            text = text.toLowerCase();
            for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
                char c = letters[i];
                // make a temporary copy of the content without the current letter
                String tmp = text.replaceAll(c + "", "");

                // subtract the new length (the length after current letter has been deleted)
                // from the original length
                int count = text.length() - tmp.length();

                // get the percentage of the occurrence of the current letter
                percentage[i] = (double) count / (double) totalNumOfLetters * 100.00;
            }
            DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat(".##"); // for formatting only
            for (int i = 0; i < percentage.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("\"" + letters[i] + "\" has a percentage of " + df2.format(percentage[i]) + "%");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Sample file:

```
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 
'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 
'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
```

Sample output:

```
"a" has a percentage of 5.88%
"b" has a percentage of 5.88%
"c" has a percentage of 5.88%
"d" has a percentage of 5.88%
"e" has a percentage of 5.88%
"f" has a percentage of 5.88%
"g" has a percentage of 5.88%
"h" has a percentage of 5.88%
"i" has a percentage of 2.94%
"j" has a percentage of 2.94%
"k" has a percentage of 2.94%
"l" has a percentage of 2.94%
"m" has a percentage of 2.94%
"n" has a percentage of 2.94%
"o" has a percentage of 2.94%
"p" has a percentage of 2.94%
"q" has a percentage of 2.94%
"r" has a percentage of 2.94%
"s" has a percentage of 2.94%
"t" has a percentage of 2.94%
"u" has a percentage of 2.94%
"v" has a percentage of 2.94%
"w" has a percentage of 2.94%
"x" has a percentage of 2.94%
"y" has a percentage of 2.94%
"z" has a percentage of 2.94%
```

Answer (score 0):

This only works if the words on that file are on ***one line***, it's ok to have whitespaces though. I might able to fix this problem tomorrow, if you still have an issue, but I have a class tomorrow, so I gotta go to sleep. Hope this helps!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CountLettersFromFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    FileReader file = new FileReader("test.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(file);

    String[] lineCharacters;
    String line;

    line=br.readLine();
    int totalLetters=0;


    lineCharacters=line.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < lineCharacters.length; i++) {
        if(!Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i)))
            totalLetters++;

    }


    double[] count = new double[255];
    int length = line.length();


    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        count[line.charAt(i)]++;
    }

    char[] ch = new char[line.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        ch[i] = line.charAt(i);
        int find = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            if (line.charAt(i) == ch[j])
                find++;
        }

        if (find == 1 && !Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i))) {
            System.out.printf("Occurance of character \"" + line.charAt(i) + "\" is: %.0f %n"
                    , count[line.charAt(i)]);
            System.out.printf("Percent occurance of character \"" +line.charAt(i) + "\" is: %.3f %n"
                    , (count[line.charAt(i)])/totalLetters,"%");
            System.out.println("\n------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

}

test.txt file includes:

salam men adam men adam salam

**OutPut:**

Occurance of character "s" is: 2

Percent occurance of character "s" is: 0.083

---

Occurance of character "a" is: 8

Percent occurance of character "a" is: 0.333

---

Occurance of character "l" is: 2

Percent occurance of character "l" is: 0.083

---

Occurance of character "m" is: 6

Percent occurance of character "m" is: 0.250

---

Occurance of character "e" is: 2

Percent occurance of character "e" is: 0.083

---

Occurance of character "n" is: 2

Percent occurance of character "n" is: 0.083

---

Occurance of character "d" is: 2

Percent occurance of character "d" is: 0.083